# Easier way of plotting table

Tags: r, plot

I have a table to plot.

[image]

After I plot, I got the decent result out of it

[image]

I code like following, but is there a faster way to do it since the data size is large and I have a few more table that I would put in a loop. Running it could take a lot of time.

```
for(i in 1:11){
     y=rep(i,length(n))
     x=wp[n,2]
     plot(x,y,col=wp[,i+2],ylim=c(1,12), xlim=c(20000000,30000000), lwd = 20,lend = 0, pch="|" )
     par(new=TRUE) }
```

Ignore the xlim, it is not that important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is important, then you need to use lattice. First we generate something like your data:

```
#number of rows of data
NROWS=1000
#number of columns of colors to plot
NCOLS = 11

colTable = matrix(
  sample(c("blue","green","white"),NROWS*NCOLS,replace=TRUE),
  ncol=NCOLS)

xcoord = sort(sample(10000,NROWS))
df = data.frame(id=1:NROWS,xcoord=xcoord,colTable,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Your function:

```
 f2 = function(){
    for(i in 1:NCOLS){
    y=rep(i,NROWS)
    x=df[,"xcoord"]
    plot(x,y,col=df[,i+2],ylim=c(0,NCOLS+1), 
         xlim=range(xcoord),pch="|" )
    par(new=TRUE) }
    dev.off()
}
```

You are constantly plotting one on top of the other, hence the axis ticks look really blur. Ideally you just render everything at one shot, but using base R plot it is not much faster.

For lattice, since you already have the data frame, you can do the following:

```
library(lattice)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

f3 = function(){
plotdf = df %>% select(2:ncol(df)) %>% 
pivot_longer(-xcoord) %>% mutate(Y=as.numeric(factor(name)))
COLS = unique(plotdf$value)
xyplot(Y ~ xcoord,data=plotdf,groups=value,
par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = "|",
                                      col = COLS)))

}
```

The plot looks something like this, you need play around with the par.settings to get what you want.

[image]

But in terms of speed, it's good

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f2=f2(),f3=f3())

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
   f2 421.9169 436.2520 460.75231 452.8287 479.28940 553.1396   100   b
   f3   9.5304   9.9318  11.54003  10.4013  11.84475  27.8273   100  a
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was not that familiar with the R. It is good to know there is package handles this kind of problem.

Comment: No problem :) You can check this https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/chapter4.pdf for more plots. Lattice is good for plotting large data.